# Random sample from a large population runs into infinite loop

Tags: c++, boost, random

I want to draw n samples from a relatively large population without replacement. So I draw random numbers and keep track of my previous choices, so I can resample whenever I drew a number twice:

```
boost::mt19937 generator;
boost::uniform_int<> distribution(0, 1669 - 1);
boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937, boost::uniform_int<> >
        gen(generator, distribution);
int n = 100;

std::vector<int> idxs;
while(static_cast<int>(idxs.size()) < n)
{
    // get random samples
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(idxs), n - idxs.size(),
                    gen);
    // remove duplicates
    // keep everything that's not duplicates to save time
    std::sort(idxs.begin(), idxs.end());
    std::vector<int>::iterator it = std::unique(idxs.begin(), idxs.end());
    idxs.resize(std::distance(idxs.begin(), it));
}
```

Unfortunately, I run into an infinite loop for the constants used above.

I added some output (that shows that it keeps picking the same number) and stopping after 10 tries for showing the problem:

```
boost::mt19937 generator;
boost::uniform_int<> distribution(0, 1669 - 1);
boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937, boost::uniform_int<> >
        gen(generator, distribution);
int n = 100;

int repeat = 0;
std::vector<int> idxs;
while(static_cast<int>(idxs.size()) < n)
{
    if(repeat++ > 10) break;
    cout << "repeat " << repeat <<
            ", " << idxs.size() << " elements" << endl;
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(idxs), n - idxs.size(),
                    gen);
    cout << "last " << idxs.back() << endl;
    std::sort(idxs.begin(), idxs.end());
    std::vector<int>::iterator it = std::unique(idxs.begin(), idxs.end());
    idxs.resize(std::distance(idxs.begin(), it));
}
```

The code prints

```
repeat 1, 0 elements
last 1347
repeat 2, 99 elements
last 1359
repeat 3, 99 elements
last 1359
```

and so on, and this seems to loop forever if I don't kill the program. This shouldn't happen, right? Am I just unlucky? Or am I doing something wrong?

**short solution**
Thanks to @jxh! Using a reference helps:

```
boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&, boost::uniform_int<> >
        gen(generator, distribution);
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstandig you code. But, isn't it easier to fill a container with range (0..1668) shuffle it and take the first ( n ) indices?

Comment: @hetepeperfan, for 1668, I agree, yes it would be. For 2e9 less so. It works for very large populations, but this is the failure case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `generate_n` creates a copy of the generator `gen` you created. So, at the end of the call to `generate_n`, the state of `gen` is unchanged. Thus, each time you re-loop, you will generate the same sequence again.

One way to fix this is to use a reference to your random number generator object in your `variate_generator`:<sup>*</sup>

```
boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&, boost::uniform_int<> >
        gen(generator, distribution);
```

<sub>* Due to my limited experience with Boost, my original suggestion was rather clumsy. I have adopted the solution implemented by the asker in this answer.</sub>

Comment: You're right, this solves the problem. Thanks! I expected the generator to take a reference, so the copy doesn't matter.